# Bounded sequence in Hilbert space contains weak convergent subsequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

In Hilbert space $H$, $\{x_n\}$ is a bounded sequence then it has a weak convergent subsequence.

Is there any short proof? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Shorter than what?  Do you have a long proof?

Comment: I think you'll want to assume a separable Hilbert space with an infinite basis $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Assuming that, work towards a diagonal argument.

Comment: There is a short proof using Banach Alaoglu...

Comment: @FrankMcGovern: Separability isn't needed, but if desired one could reduce to the separable case by considering the Hilbert subspace generated by $\{x_n\}$.

Comment: Thanks for you hints and explanation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose $M$ bounds the sequence. Then, if we think of $H$ as sitting inside $H^{**}$, then for any $T \in H^\ast$ with $\|T\| \leq 1$, we have $\|x_n(T)\| = \|Tx_n\| \leq \|x_n\| \leq M$, so the operator norms of the $x_n$ thought of as operators on $H^\ast$ are bounded by $M$. Apply Banach-Alaoglu. (To the unit ball of $H^{\ast \ast}$.)

Comment: So you only needed a reflexive Banach space? That's very nice!

Comment: @N.U. yes, and in fact reflexive Banach spaces are characterized by the property in the OP. This follows from the [Eberlein-Smulyan theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberlein-Smulian_theorem) combined with Kakutani's theorem that a Banach space is reflexive iff its unit ball is weakly compact.