# Short proof of sequential Banach Alaoglu for Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Do you know of a short proof of the fact that bounded sequences in Hilbert spaces admit weakly converging subsequences?

If the space is separable, then the common sequential-version proof is what I consider short enough. Also, the common proof of the Heine-Borel-compactness Banach-Alaoglu is short enough. Only, first proving the Heine-Borel-compactness Banach-Alaoglu and then proving Eberlein-Smulian is too long for me. In particular, my problem would be solved if Eberlein-Smulian was evident for Hilbert spaces.

Comment: oh no, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the link in the first comment reveals, one may restrict considerations to the Hilbert-Space generated by the sequence, which is obviously separable.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396961/bounded-sequence-in-hilbert-space-contains-weak-convergent-subsequence) is the (deleted above) link.