# How to use Banach-Alaoglu here?

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I am confused by [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/396981/995003) which says “apply Banach-Alaoglu to the unit ball of $H^{**}$”. I can’t see how to get the result we desired by this. Does it means

> Since $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence in $H^{**}$, it has a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ on the $w^{*}$-compact unit ball of $H^{*}$, so $x_{n_k}\rightharpoonup x_n$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I might be wrong but I think you need the Eberlein-Smulian theorem ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberlein%E2%80%93%C5%A0mulian_theorem ).  This is because the implication of compactness to sequential compactness holds for I-countable spaces which is not the case in general for dual spaces with the weak topology.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.